# How to create custom type of page with its own index in octopress?

Tags: octopress

Just like this page http://brandonmathis.com/projects/, how can I create a *project* with its own index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

Create a directory called projects in your Octopress site root. Inside it, put a file 'index.html' and a directory _posts: so you'll have something along the lines of this:

```
_layouts/
_plugins/
_posts/
    some_post_that_is_not_a_project.md
projects/
    index.html
    _posts/
        some_project.md
        some_other_project.md
index.html
config.yml
```

Any post you make inside that _posts directory will automatically belong to the 'projects' category. This means that you can then put something like the following in projects/index.html:

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.categories.projects %}
    <li>
    <a href="/{ post.permalink }}">
        <img src="{{ post.image }} alt="{{ post.title }}></img>
        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ post.summary }}</p>
    </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And then have posts like this:

```
---
title: Fancy buttons
image: /path/to/some/image.jpg
summary: |
    I created Fancy Buttons (a Compass plugin) to make it easy to design gorgeous
    customizable CSS buttons in seconds.
|
---

Here is the longer content of this post etc etc which will
appear on the project page itself...
```

This is a nice way of doing it, because you have a clear, sensible directory structure that's easy to navigate and maintain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How so? If it errored, I may have made a typo or syntax error. If it just didn't do what you want, you would do well to explain how. I'm happy to give you more help to solve your problem, but I need more information to do so. For a start, I just noticed that my directory structure originally had the projects/ directory beginning with an underscore. That was a typo that I've just corrected.

Comment: It's not the `_project` typo issue. Octopress seems to ignore any folders started with underline. But I finally solved it ;)